# WPF - how to hide menu on mouse leave?

Tags: wpf, hide, menuitem, mouseleave

I'm very very new to WPF and I've been struggling for a couple of days now on how to hide a sub-menu of a MenuItem when the mouse leaves the sub-menu.

I've tried applying the trigger directly on the parent MenuItem but this only applies to its header. I've tried to manipulate the MenuItem.ItemsPanel I haven't had any success.

I have managed to wrap the children in a Menu control (inside the parent MenuItem) and apply the trigger on it but there are unwanted side effects (like all Menu is highlighted instead of one item).

Any help will be appreciated,

Idan

```
<Menu .... >
    <MenuItem .... > // parent MenuItem
        <MenuItem .... />
        <MenuItem .... />
        <MenuItem .... />
        <MenuItem .... />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: paste your source code :) it will help us to find the solution

Comment: You *do* realise that that is the normal behaviour of *all* popup controls, don't you? You click on something and they open, then you either need to click on an item to select an option, or something away from the control to close the popup. That is the behaviour that your users will be used to and you should leave it as it is.

Comment: I know and appreciate your comment, but in this particular case that is what I was instructed to do.. that's what you get when you have a boss (:

Comment: did you solve the problem? I've got the same and don't know what to do.please help me too

Comment: I didn't find any solution, I just left it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to XAML and this may not be perfect but it works for me - I needed the same function and came up with this after many hours of searching and trying, this is why I wanted to post it because I could not find the answer anywhere. There is extra code for styling and alignment but you can ignore it:

**Only - Xaml for closing the menu on mouse leave:**

```
 <!--.........Override PopUp so it can close on Mouse Leave + Style ----------------------------------->            
                    <!--#3-Top Menu - MenuItem-->
                    <Style x:Key="menu_TopMenu_MenuItem_Style" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                            
                            
                            <ControlTemplate x:Name="menuItem" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="templateRoot"  BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        
                                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                       
                                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False"  IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="None" Placement="Bottom">
                                            <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder">
                                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" 
                                              Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}"
                                              Background="Blue" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                                    <Grid  RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">   
                                                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Stroke="#8a919c"  RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" StrokeThickness="1" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}">
                                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF404957" Offset="0.144"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF2B3F47" Offset="0.994"/>
                                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Rectangle.Fill>    
                                                            </Rectangle>
                                                        </Canvas>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ScrollViewer>
                                            </Border>    
                                        </Popup>
                                        
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
            
                                
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                
                                    
                                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="#FF576DB9" />
                                    </Trigger>
            
            
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#7F26DACA"/>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26DAB9"/>
            
                                        
                                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="true"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                    </Trigger>
            
                                  
                                       
                                    
            
                                    <!--On - MouseLeave - Close PopUp - "Menu" -->
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="false" />
                                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            
                                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="false"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
            
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            
                        </Setter.Value>  
                    </Setter>
```

=========================================================================
**Detailed:**

**#1 - MainWindow.xaml - File - "The Menu code bellow":**

```
<Window x:Class="PaintApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PaintApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"   
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">


    <!--GRID-->
    <Grid x:Name="grid_MainGrid">
<!--..............................The Menu Code....................................................-->  

        <!--Top Menu-->
        <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel_Menu_TopMenu" Style="{DynamicResource dockPanel_Menu_TopMenu_Style}">
            <Menu x:Name="menu_TopMenu" Style="{DynamicResource menu_TopMenu_Style}">

                <MenuItem Header="File" Style="{DynamicResource menu_TopMenu_MenuItem_Style}">
                    <MenuItem Header="New"/>
                    <Separator Style="{DynamicResource menu_TopMenu_Seperator_Style}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
                    <Separator Style="{DynamicResource menu_TopMenu_Seperator_Style}"/>
                    <MenuItem  Header="Save"/>

                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Close" Style="{DynamicResource menu_TopMenu_MenuItem_Style}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Open" Style="{DynamicResource menu_TopMenu_MenuItem_Style}"/>
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
```

**#2 -The Resource Dictionary File** - **The Styles**- **maintheme.xaml** - I am placing my styles in a separate file so I can change the theme dynamically

```
     <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                                     x:Class="PaintApp.maintheme"
                                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PaintApp">
                
                
           <!--..........Only For Style and alignment if you dont care about the style ignore this....................................................-->  
                <!--#1 - Top Menu-DockPanel-->
                <Style x:Key="dockPanel_Menu_TopMenu_Style" TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            
            
                
                
          
        
     <!--..........Only For Style and alignment if you dont care about the style ignore this....................................................-->  
                <!--#2-Top Menu-Menu-->
                <Style x:Key="menu_TopMenu_Style" TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3E434B"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFA9B"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
                </Style>
            
         
    
       
            
                  
    <!--.........Override PopUp so it can close on Mouse Leave + Style ----------------------------------->            
                <!--#3-Top Menu - MenuItem-->
                <Style x:Key="menu_TopMenu_MenuItem_Style" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                        
                        
                        <ControlTemplate x:Name="menuItem" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="templateRoot"  BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                   
                                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False"  IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="None" Placement="Bottom">
                                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder">
                                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" 
                                          Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}"
                                          Background="Blue" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                                <Grid  RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">   
                                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Stroke="#8a919c"  RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" StrokeThickness="1" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}">
                                                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF404957" Offset="0.144"/>
                                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF2B3F47" Offset="0.994"/>
                                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                            </Rectangle.Fill>    
                                                        </Rectangle>
                                                    </Canvas>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ScrollViewer>
                                        </Border>    
                                    </Popup>
                                    
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
        
                            
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            
                                
                                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="#FF576DB9" />
                                </Trigger>
        
        
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#7F26DACA"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26DAB9"/>
        
                                    
                                    <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="true"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                </Trigger>
        
                              
                                   
                                
        
                                <!--On - MouseLeave - Close PopUp - "Menu" -->
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="false" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        
                                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="false"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                </MultiTrigger>
        
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        
                    </Setter.Value>  
                </Setter>
        
                
    
<!--......SubMenus....Only For Style and alignment if you dont care about the style ignore this....................................................-->             
        
                <!--Top - Menu - SUB - MenuItems-->
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>   
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                    <Border x:Name="subMenuitemBorder" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Uid="Border_38">
                                        <Grid x:Name="bg"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderHost" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                                                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <!--<Border BorderBrush="#FF60626A" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1"  Margin="10, 0, 10, -5">-->
                                                        <TextBlock Padding="30, 3,30, 5"  Text="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"/>
                                                        <!--</Border>-->
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>  
                                            </ContentPresenter>    
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
        
        
                                    
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="subMenuitemBorder" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="subMenuitemBorder" Value="#7F26A0DA"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>  
                                    
                                </ControlTemplate>    
                            </Setter.Value>  
                        </Setter>   
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>     
            </Style>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <!--..........Only For Style and alignment if you dont care about the style ignore this....................................................--> 
        
            <!--Top - Menu Seperator-->
            <Style x:Key="menu_TopMenu_Seperator_Style" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,1,10,1"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                            <Border 
                                BorderBrush="#FF6A667E" 
                                BorderThickness="1" 
                                Background="Red"
                                Height="1" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

**#3 - The App.xaml file - Because I use seperate file for the styles**

```
<Application x:Class="PaintApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PaintApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">


    <Application.Resources>

        <!--Seperate file for the styles-->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="maintheme.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>    
        </ResourceDictionary>   
        <!--Seperate file for the styles-->

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```